What exactly is the length field in SHA-512 padding?
If I am using SHA-512 on a message and need to determine the padding field and length field, how do I determine the length field? I think I understand the padding, but not the length field.
For instance, State the value of the padding field P and the value of the length field L in SHA-512 if the length of the message to be signed is 1921 bits.
So the padding bits would be one 1's and 1022 0's. i just can't get the hold of what do you mean by "it's the length of the message in bits (without padding)." can someone please explain this is laymen terms?

If "using SHA-512 on a message" then one is not concerned by the padding field and length field. These are handled by the implementation of SHA-512. The question is about how SHA-512 works internally, not about using it. Related question

Have a look at RFC6234
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6234#section-4.2
You add one (1) at the end of your input message (step a), resulting in an input message length of 1922. Then you append zeros until the operation (InMsgLen + 1 + AppendedZeros) mod 1024 = 896 (step b). In your case, AppendedZeros will be 1022 (1921 + 1 + 1022) mod 1024 = 896. You can either append 1022 zeros, or you can reduce your message by 2 bits, in which case you will remove the need for so many zeros. Then, at step c, you add 16 bytes (which so happen to be 128 bits) which represent the length of your input message (which is 1921).

c. Then append the 128-bit block that is L in binary >representation. After appending this block, the length of the message will be a multiple of 1024 bits.


so that means that after step (b) i just need to add 128 ( original message(1921) converted in binary ) and add InMsgLen + 1 + AppendedZeros = 128 and this will give me the multiple of 1024.

@HarjotSingh: no. The padding field L is the 128-bit bitstring which encodes in binary the decimal number 1921, the way 00100101 is the 8-bit bitstring which encodes in binary the decimal number 37 (all per big-endian convention)

@HarjotSingh is all clear now?
